# What does WISC (stack) mean?

Tags: terminology

[LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) is a well-known acronym for the software/technology bundle/stack representing [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), [Apache](http://www.apache.org/), [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), [PHP](http://www.php.net/). There are a few passing references on the Web that use the acronym *WISC* to speak of the *other* (supposedly Microsoft-centric) software/technology bundle/stack in contrast to LAMP. There is, however, no Wikipedia entry on WISC at this time nor any relevant [results from googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=wisc+stack). Does the following seem like the right de-composition of the WISC acronym?

- W = [Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/windows)
- I = [Internet Information Services (IIS)](http://www.microsoft.com/iis)
- S = [SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver)
- C = [C#](http://www.microsoft.com/vcsharp)

If yes, is there a Web reference that coins the WISC acronym? If no, is there another acronym used to represent the Microsoft-centric stack when comparing with LAMP?

P.S. First sighting of WISC at “[ASP.NET Caching vs. memcached: Seeking Efficient Data Partitioning, Lookup, and Retrieval](http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2007/07/05/ASPNETCachingVsMemcachedSeekingEfficientDataPartitioningLookupAndRetrieval.aspx)”.

Comment: It's not WISC, it's RISC (used by LITHP programmers). 
I'll get me coat.

Comment: [Wechsler Intelligence Scale for Children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wechsler_Intelligence_Scale_for_Children)

Comment: Why do people feel compelled to fit reality to the acronym and not vice-versa?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question.

Comment: I am currently developing Kotlin apps with a No SQL database, delivered by an Apache server running on a Windows machine.

Just so I can tell people about my tech stack.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Or WISA:
Windows, IIS, SQL Server, ASP.net

I don't know why anyone would want to call it WISC, as these people are essentially saying "We will never ever use VB.NET, IronPython, IronRuby, F# or any other .NET Language". Also calling it .NET (WISN) sounds a bit weird as well, since ASP.NET is the Web-Technology of .NET. But well, that's the good things about acronyms and standard. Everyone has its own.

Comment: Do you have any links where WISA is coined? Interestingly, Wikipedia redirects to LAMP when you search for WISA.

Comment: I don't have any source, i remember it coming up after some time Heise coined LAMP (http://www.heise.de/ct/english/98/12/230/) in Germany

Comment: I think WINS (Windows, IIS, .NET, SQL) sounds more marketing-friendly, but it's been used in other acronyms before.

Comment: WINS also doesn't follow the ordering of LAMP with respect to the technologies.

Answer (score 15):

That looks correct although I would have called it WISN (Wizzen) with .NET at the end rather than a particular language within the .NET ecosphere.

The best one is:

FreeBSD
Apache
PostgreSQL
Ruby (FAPpeR) / Perl/PHP (FAPP!) ...

Comment: Microsoft will probably market it as WIS.NET though :(

Comment: hehehe... FAPpeR * giggles *

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking for something more-or-less like LAMP except it runs on Windows,
I usually see

- WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP)
- WIMP (MS Windows; MS IIS (Internet Information Services); MySQL,
  MS SQL Server or MS Access; PHP, Perl, or Python).

On a completely unrelated topic,

When I use the term "WISC", I'm always talking about some WISC ([writable instruction set computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode#Writable_control_stores)) design, such as the Intel Xeon. Many of them "stack computers" (stack machines).
Perhaps the most famous are the WISC CPU/16 and the WISC CPU/32 designed by [Philip Koopman; each design is a "stack computer"](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/stack.html) (as opposed to a "memory-to-memory machine" or "RISC" or "accumulator machine").